# Boundedness and norm of a linear operator

Tags: operator-theory, normed-spaces

> Consider the linear operator $T : C[-\pi,\pi] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by 
>   $$ Tf := \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t)\sin(t)\phantom{.}dt $$
>   Show that $T$ is bounded and find its norm $\|T\|$. Consider $\|f\|$ as the infinity/sup-norm, i.e. $\|f\|_{\infty}$.

How may I show this? I am not sure how to proceed.

My work so far:

To see that $\|T\|$ is bounded, we make use of the fact that $-1 \leqslant \sin(t) \leqslant 1$ for all $t \in [-\pi,\pi]$. Then,
\begin{align*}
    \|Tf\| = \bigg\| \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t)\sin(t)\phantom{.}dt \bigg\|_{\infty} \leqslant \bigg\|_{\infty} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t)\phantom{.}dt \bigg \| = \| f\|_{\infty}
\end{align*}
so we have that $\|T\|$ is bounded and $\|T\|  \leqslant 1$.....

Comment: I would start with writing down the definition of the norm and what bounded means.

Comment: You need to mention the norm $C[-\pi,\pi]$ is equipped with.

Comment: To show it's bounded, you need to show there is a constant $c$ such that $||Tf||\leq{c}||f||$ for every $f\in{C}$. But, as Nikolaos says, for that we need to know which norm $||f||$ is...

Comment: @iiivooo: Do you really worry about the definitions here? IMHO, everybody (I mean literally everybody) with some descent enough familiarity in functional analysis in order to answer this question will be able to understand from the context what is understood under boundedness and what norm is considered. In that case, these kind of remarks seem absolute pedantry.

Comment: @iiivooo: I think it is more constructive to mention that the sup-norm seems reasonable. (See answer below!)

Comment: @Freeze_S If you would look in the history of this question, you would see that first version of this question contained no effort at all from the OP and he was asking how he should start. And therefore my comment was meant as a hint how to start! BTW. maybe everybody knows the definition of norm, but there was no proof that OP knows the definition in the time I wrote the comment!

Comment: @iiivooo: Good point!! In that case I totally agree with you: It's best for the OP to write out the definitions. This usually helps finding an answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that we're working with the supremal norm on f, then:

$\int _{-\pi} ^{\pi} f(t) \sin(t) dt \leq \int _{-\pi} ^{\pi} |f(t)| |\sin(t)| dt \leq \int _{-\pi} ^{\pi} sup _{x \in [-\pi, \pi]}|f(x)| |\sin(t)|dt \leq \int _{-\pi} ^{\pi} 1 |\sin(t)|dt$ , so $||T|| \leq \int _{-\pi} ^{\pi} |\sin(t)| dt$

Now we can come arbitrarily close to this norm with something that converges to $sgn(x)$, for example $f(t) = -1 $ for $ t \leq - \frac{1}{n}, 
                            =  1 $ for $ t \geq \frac{1}{n},
                            =  nt $ for $  -\frac{1}{n} \leq t \leq \frac{1}{n}$

which shows that definitely $||T|| \geq \int _{-\pi} ^{\pi} |\sin(t)| dt - \frac{2}{n}$  $ \forall n \in \mathbb{N} $